# What is the state of the art on triangle-free strongly regular graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, strongly-regular-graph

From what I've read I've gathered the following facts:

- There are seven known such graphs.
- Certain parameter sets are ruled out by the Krein conditions and the absolute bound.
- Beyond that, little or nothing is known.

Am I missing something? I have read Biggs's [report](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/norman/SRNT.pdf) which lists all small feasible parameter sets and apparently [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jcd.20145/abstract) shows that (324,57,0,12) is infeasible.

Is something else known about this problem?

Answer (score 6):

The complete bipartite graphs $K_{n,n}$ are strongly regular and triangle-free.
This nitpicking aside, your summary is accurate.

Comment: In fact, 20 years ago (almost) Chris published his "Problems in Algebraic Combinatorics" in a very early volume of the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics asking among other things, "Is there an eighth triangle-free SRG?" the answer to which is still unknown.

Answer (score 3):

an update of Biggs's list (complete up to 1300 vertices) is maintained [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html) by Andries Brouwer.

for a list of open problems and research directions, a good starting point could be Matan Ziv-Av's recent presentations [2011](http://larmor.nuigalway.ie/~detinko/Matan.pdf) --- [2013](http://www.risc.jku.at/conferences/scss2013/talks/ziv_av.pdf) and conference [paper](http://www.easychair.org/publications/?page=131511239).